# forward incoming reverse proxy request to websocket server then forward again to local webserver with client websocket

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket

I want to create an aplication to handle request from reverse proxy apache server with websocket.

My goal, is i can make my local webserver can go online. Because, i use mobile carrier that dont give me public ip, or outbound open port webserver.

in my mind, i think its possible to do. with this scheme.

It needs

1. webserver that can be access by public as reverse proxy.
2. Forward any request from reverse proxy to websocket server.
3. Client connect to websocket server.
4. Client run webserver in local
5. Any request from websocket server will forward to client websocket then forward to webserver in local.

client request -> reverse proxy webserver public -> websocket server public -> websocket client -> local webserver.

The advantage with this, my local webserver always can online with any connection, cellular carrier, wifi public and hide any implement code safely.

Is there already outhere already implements this?